# Java project does not recognise imports from a generated jar file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I am using the command line `jar cvfm server-model.jar nz` to generate a jar file called `server-model.jar`

Some output:

```
adding: nz/api/pojos/core/util/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: nz/api/pojos/core/util/RenderMarkdownReqMsg.java(in = 845) (out= 283)(deflated 66%)
adding: nz/api/pojos/core/util/RenderMarkdownRespMsg.java(in = 904) (out= 296)(deflated 67%)
```

After that I am running `jar -tvf server-model.jar`

Some output:

```
   0 Wed Jul 02 16:52:20 NZST 2014 nz/api/pojos/core/util/
  845 Wed Jul 02 16:52:20 NZST 2014 nz/api/pojos/core/util/RenderMarkdownReqMsg.java
   904 Wed Jul 02 16:52:20 NZST 2014 nz/api/pojos/core/util/RenderMarkdownRespMsg.java
```

My problem is that a simple Java project (because I tried almost everything and the project actually use Maven) can not use those classes because the import statement does not recognise them.

It think there is a problem with the MANIFEST.MF and/or classpath. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Comment: You should be making use of a build tool like Ant or even Maven to do this, that's there job :P

Comment: This code is auto-generated using the Sun Code Model and it gonna be generated as maven project and deployed into Sonatype Nexus by an Atlasssian Bamboo Continuous Delivery Server job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your jar file contains *source* code - if you want to use a jar file as a library in a project, you need to compile the source code first, and put the *class files* in the jar file.

For example:

```
$ javac -d bin src/nz/api/pojos/core/util/*.java
$ jar -C bin -cvf server-model.jar nz
```

Then running `jar tvf server-model.jar` you should see the `.class` files.

You may *also* want to include the source code in the jar file, as then IDEs can pick up the source and allow you to see it in your main project, and debug into that code too. But it's not required for *building*.